# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, summation

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$ if $a_n$ is non-negative. Call the first series $A$ and the second series $B$. I'm just assuming that the definition of the latter series is $B:=\sup R$, where $R:=\left\{\sum_{n\in K}a_n\mid K\subset\mathbb{N} \ \text{is finite}\right\}$. I wasn't given one in my textbook, so I'm just assuming that's it.

$(\leq)$: Suppose $\{s_m\}$ is the sequence of partial sums for $\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m$. Then $s_n=\sum_{j=1}^na_m$. Since this is a finite sum, the order of the terms doesn't matter, and so I can write this as $\sum_{j\in K} a_j$ such that $\operatorname{card}(K)=n$. So each $s_m\in R\implies s_m\leq B \ \forall n\geq 1$. Thus, $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_m\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}B=B$

$(\geq)$: Let $x$ be any element of $R$. So for some finite $K\subset\mathbb{N}$, we have $x=\sum_{n\in K}a_n$. Suppose $M$ is the largest element of $K$. Then since the terms $a_n$ are non-negative, we have $x\leq\sum_{j=1}^ma_j$ for all $m\geq M$. Thus, $x\leq\sum_{j=1}^ma_j\leq\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^ma_j=A$ for every $x\in R$. Thus, $A$ is an upper bound for $R$. Since $B$ is the least upper bound for $R$, we have $A\geq B$.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my argument?

Comment: I might be missing something, but aren't they exactly the same series (the same sequence $a_n$ summed over the same domain)?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your argument.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut : Yes, you're missing something. To be continued$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy What?

Comment: When you write \text{sup} instead of \sup then you don't get proper spacing in things like $a\sup b$ (so that you see $\text{sup} R$ rather than $\sup R$ and in a displayed setting as opposed to an inline setting the difference between \text{sup}_{x\in S} f(x) and \sup_{x\in S} f(x) is this: $$ \text{sup}_{x\in S} f(x) \quad \text{versus} \quad \sup_{x\in S} f(x) $$ Similarly with \text{lim} versus \lim. $\qquad$

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I guess the point is that in the series $B$, there isn't a particular order in which the terms $a_n$ are summed, but there is for the series $A$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut : The meaning of $\displaystyle \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} a_n$, when $a_n\ge0$ for every $n$, is $\displaystyle \sup\left\{ \sum_{n\in K} a_n \mid K\subseteq\mathbb N \text{ is finite}\right\}.$ The meaning of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n.$ The problem is to prove that those are the same. $\qquad$

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut To give a specific example where they would not be equal, consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{N}} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. The first one exists by the alternating series test and the second one doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! I didn't catch that.